# Superluminous scissors with a twist

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

The superluminous scissors are a standard problem in special relativity. (For those who don't know: take ultra-long scissors and closed them. The first instinct is to think that the point where the blades meet travels faster than light. But that's not true because the information traveling through the blades is always slower than light and hence the scissors would bend.)

Now what if, instead of closing the scissors conventionally, I attached a large number of robots to each blade that can push the scissors closed. Each robot carries a clock synchronized to all other clocks. And the robots are programmed to start pushing at exactly the same time to an extend that closes the scissors without bending the blades (like normal-sized scissors).

In this scenario, the touching point of the blades travels faster than the speed of light. And that's ok because no information travels with it. But what if the blades were train tracks and I sat in an cart pushed ahead by the tracks closing. What prevents me from traveling faster than the speed of light?
(And of course the tracks, the robots, the cart, and I are indestructible as well as the robots are infinitely strong. So please no answers like "you will die" or "things will break".)

I want to adapt my setup slightly after this answer:

> Once the blades start to move, the robots will no longer be in the same inertial frame, and so their clocks will no longer be synchronised

> the "classical" idea of rigidity has to be given up when dealing with bodies undergoing relativistic motion. For example, see the Ehrenfest Paradox.

The tracks are not attached at one end (like scissor blades would be) but the robots push two long rigid tracks that are at a small angle to each other. Then the robots are in in the same reference frame. Also my cart and I are point-like. How does the superluminousity break down now?

Comment: 1) Once the blades start to move, the robots will no longer be in the same inertial frame, and so their clocks will no longer be synchronised, would they? As a result I would imagine the blades becoming "bendy", as in the previous case. 
2) Incidentally, "Things will break" is a perfectly valid concern: the "classical" idea of rigidity has to be given up when dealing with bodies undergoing relativistic motion. For example, see the [Ehrenfest Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox).

Comment: I think the issue is in part that the robots would not actually be able to get the blade tips moving towards each other at greater than or equal to the speed of light in the first place.

Comment: @thorimur How do you mean that? Say the far ends are a distance x apart and the tracks approach each other at the speed of light relative to each other. Then the crossing point will always travel faster than the speed of light if it was further than x away from the ends.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for the tracks to approach each other at the speed of light relative to each other in the first place, though. (Remember, spatial velocity is not additive in relativity: if two particles are moving apart from each other both at $c/2$, it's not the case that one is moving at the speed of light relative to the other!)

Comment: But I do think it is possible to get the crossing point moving faster than light regardless. The issue, then, is simply that the force applied to the cart by the closing blades would not actually be able to accelerate the cart up to the speed of light (and therefore not up to the speed of the crossing point), even though we'd expect the normal force to scale "as needed" in nonrelativistic settings. You'd wind up squashing the cart or not being able to move the scissors any further eventually, if I have the picture right, I think.

Comment: I dislike questions where the questioner places restrictions on the answer. “Things will break” is a perfectly valid answer, and you have no justification for rejecting it a priori. That you did indicates that you know the answer to your question already, you just don’t like it.

Comment: Just how could the clocks be synchronized? If they are synchronized together then moved apart they will no longer be in synchronization after moving.

Answer (score 2):

If you managed to build your scissorgun in real life then you would have something, but as a mere thought experiment, the resolution is simple: your assumptions are logically inconsistent.

At each $x$ along the closing scissors you have to push the cart from $x$ to $x+dx$ in a time less than $dx/c$, and that simply can't be done. If you push at separated spacetime locations then the cart won't arrive at the next location in time for the next push. If you push continuously then whatever does the pushing has to move faster than $c$, leading to an infinite regress.

You ask how your machine breaks down, as though it's already built, but what you should ask is how it could be built in the first place. You've provided no information about the composition of the indestructible cart or the nature of the irresistible force to be applied to it. Much as in the classic thought-experiment of FTL communication via an infinitely rigid rod, the materials you need for your machine can't be sourced anywhere. Their existence is ruled out by special relativity. If you build it from materials that are physically possible, then the result will depend on the details of the construction, but broadly speaking, "things will break".